# Twitter stream returns data with accents too

Tags: python, twitter, streaming, tweepy, diacritics

I am using tweepy to filter data based on a certain keyword. Apart from the desired result, I get all those tweets containing that keyword followed by an accented vowel too.

I use the following code:

```
stream.filter(track=[searchKeyword])
```

searchKeyword is input from command prompt.

For e.g., if the search keyword is test, I get tweets with the word testí, testía  too. How do I filter such tweets?

Comment: I don't think so, looking over the [`track` documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#track).

Comment: I am creating a bot and without resolving this issue my bot would be a bug bot. How else do you think I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Filter further in your code?